# C# Check if string contains any item in stringlist

Tags: c#, string, list, windows-forms-designer

How do I check if my `input`-string contains any strings in my string-`list`?
I looked some solutions up, but most of them weren't what I was looking for and others were in Python and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq and string.Contains

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var values = new List<string> { "some", "input", "values" };
        var input1 = "this does not have any match";
        Console.WriteLine("Input1 contains some match? " + values.Any(v => input1.Contains(v)));

        var input2 = "this does have some match";
        Console.WriteLine("Input2 contains some match? " + values.Any(v => input2.Contains(v)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that `=>` is a lambda expression, but I still don't know what it actually means....and where does the `v` come from? Sorry, kinda new to this.

Comment: Linq's enumerable 'Any' checks if the collection has at least, one value that matchs the function passed as parameter. The function is v => input1.Contains(v). Just one parameter (v with the inferred type from the collection) and the body function is inpu1.Contains(v)

Comment: It's just a csharp way of write anonymous or lambda functions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions